# How to load the saved tokenizer from pretrained model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I fine-tuned a pretrained BERT model in Pytorch using huggingface transformer. All the training/validation is done on a GPU in cloud.

At the end of the training, I save the model and tokenizer like below:

```
best_model.save_pretrained('./saved_model/')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('./saved_model/')
```

This creates below files in the `saved_model` directory:

```
config.json
added_token.json
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
vocab.txt
pytorch_model.bin
```

Now, I download the `saved_model` directory in my computer and want to load the model and tokenizer. I can load the model like below

`model = torch.load('./saved_model/pytorch_model.bin',map_location=torch.device('cpu'))`

But how do I load the tokenizer? I am new to pytorch and not sure because there are multiple files. Probably I am not saving the model in the right way?

Comment: `tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('./saved_model/')`

Comment: I am sure that it must work. Let me know if it works, I shall post it as answer.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa yes, post it as an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the syntax, it is the directory of the pre-trained model that you are supposed to pass. Hence, the correct way to load tokenizer must be:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(<Path to the directory containing pretrained model/tokenizer>)
```

In your case:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('./saved_model/')
```

`./saved_model` here is the directory where you'll be saving your pretrained model and tokenizer.

Comment: How to make this reference to local model work in docker?  I'm putting my model and tokenizer in a folder called "./saved" and I get the following error. Looks like Docker is still looking for the config, model, tokenizer files from hugging face.

Comment: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/saved/resolve/main/config.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 505, in get_config_dict
    user_agent=user_agent,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/file_utils.py", line 1337,

Comment: any idea, how can we do same stuff in scala sparknlp implementation? I am trying to load my own tokenizer into the pipeline but keep running into compatibility issues.

Comment: Have never used Scala or Spark. Sorry about that :(

Comment: What if it's not bert? Is there a way to autodetect?

Comment: Insert of 'BertTokenizer' use 'AutoTokenizer'

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the model from your local. don't forget `local_files_only=True`

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("your_local_address",  local_files_only=True)

model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("your_local_address", local_files_only=True)
```