# Huggingface saving tokenizer

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to save the tokenizer in huggingface so that I can load it later from a container where I don't need access to the internet.

```py
BASE_MODEL = "distilbert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(BASE_MODEL)
tokenizer.save_vocabulary("./models/tokenizer/")
tokenizer2 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")
```

However, the last line is giving the error:

```py
OSError: Can't load config for './models/tokenizer3/'. Make sure that:

- './models/tokenizer3/' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or './models/tokenizer3/' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

**transformers version: 3.1.0**

[How to load the saved tokenizer from pretrained model in Pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417374/how-to-load-the-saved-tokenizer-from-pretrained-model-in-pytorch) didn't help unfortunately.

### Edit 1

Thanks to @ashwin's answer below I tried `save_pretrained` instead, and I get the following error:

```py
OSError: Can't load config for './models/tokenizer/'. Make sure that:

- './models/tokenizer/' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or './models/tokenizer/' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

the contents of the tokenizer folder is below:
[image]

I tried renaming `tokenizer_config.json` to `config.json` and then I got the error:

```py
ValueError: Unrecognized model in ./models/tokenizer/. Should have a `model_type` key in its config.json, or contain one of the following strings in its name: retribert, t5, mobilebert, distilbert, albert, camembert, xlm-roberta, pegasus, marian, mbart, bart, reformer, longformer, roberta, flaubert, bert, openai-gpt, gpt2, transfo-xl, xlnet, xlm, ctrl, electra, encoder-decoder
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`save_vocabulary()`, saves only the vocabulary file of the tokenizer (List of BPE tokens).

To save the entire tokenizer, you should use `save_pretrained()`

Thus, as follows:

```
BASE_MODEL = "distilbert-base-multilingual-cased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(BASE_MODEL)
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")
tokenizer2 = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")
```

Edit:

for some unknown reason:
instead of

`tokenizer2 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")`

using

`tokenizer2 = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained("./models/tokenizer/")`

works.

Comment: Tried looking into it. It seems like a bug. And as you have figured out it saves tokenizer_config.json and expects config.json.

Comment: As a workaround, since you are not modifying the tokenizer, you get model using `from_pretrained`, then save the model. You can also load the tokenizer from the saved model. This should be a tentative workaround.

Comment: Please check out the modification.

Comment: @sachinruk: Just in case you have to work with the AutoTokenizers, you have to save the corresponding config as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472238/autotokenizer-from-pretrained-fails-to-load-locally-saved-pretrained-tokenizer/62664374#62664374).

Comment: @cronoik, I checked your answer in the other post. However, I was curious to know if there is any raised issue on github? I could not find any issue concerning this problem.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Yes, there is. I have linked to it in the first sentence :) But the [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4197) was closed. I will reopen it tomorrow and provide a patch.

Comment: That's awesome :)

Comment: excuse me does evaluate the captioning for the images will be apply to testing for example if i'm using coco ?

Answer (score 3):

Renaming "tokenizer_config.json" file -- the one created by save_pretrained() function -- to "config.json" solved the same issue on my environment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save both your model and tokenizer in the same directory. HuggingFace is actually looking for the config.json file of your model, so renaming the tokenizer_config.json would not solve the issue

Comment: tokenizer.save_pretrained("/home/pchhapolika/Bert_multilingual_exp_TCM/model_mlm_exp1") produces 4 files when I add new tokens. ideally when I save tokenizer it should produce only one tokenizer.json file?